# DateTime off an Hour in Microsoft WepAPI 2.2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

We recently converted to WepAPI 2.2 using OData4. We are running into a strange issue with a DateTime field.

I know that when JQuery sends over the datetime value to the Contoller, it is converted correctly to UTC because I verified the value through Fiddler. FYI, the date is entered as local time (Pacific Daylight Savings Time).

When the date gets to the ODataController, .Net automatically converts the UTC value back to local time. However, it is an hour behind.

I checked the web server and it is set up for daylights savings time.

I've done tons of searches, but cannot find a clue. Does anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE: The time goes over the wire as 2015-05-02T01:00:00.000Z. That is supposed to be 5/5/2015 6:00 PM Pacific Daylight Time

Answer (score 0):

.Net or the server is using the Pacific Standard Time Timezone (I'm in California) from windows. The PST timezone says it supports Daylights Savings, however the UTC offset is 8 (which is fine for PST, but PDT is offset by 7). There does not appear to be a Pacific Daylight Time Timezone loaded on the machine.